# CAML Query filtering data within a date range

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, caml

I want to retrieve items within a daterange from an `SPList`. The start date will be today and end date will be the day after 30 days from today. Here is my CAML query.

```
query.Query = string.Concat(@
    "<Where>
        <And>
          <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>
          </Geq>
          <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'><Today offset='30'/></Value>
          </Leq>
       </And>
     </Where>
     <OrderBy>
       <FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' />
     </OrderBy>");
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
```

But this will return only the items having today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using `OffsetDays` or `Offset` not `offset` in the `<Today/>` value...

```
query.Query = string.Concat(@
    "<Where>
        <And>
          <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>
          </Geq>
          <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='30'/></Value>
          </Leq>
       </And>
     </Where>
     <OrderBy>
       <FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' />
     </OrderBy>");
```

[What is the difference between CAML Offset and OffsetDays?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135968/what-is-the-difference-between-caml-offset-and-offsetdays)

Alternatively you could create `DateTime` objects and use the  [SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime.aspx)